# Close all windows except the current one and NERDTree

Tags: vim-windows, plugin-nerdtree

I know about `:only` and <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>.

But I want to keep NERDTree window untouched. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This solution only works with vim 8+**

You can add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
function! OnlyAndNerdtree()
    let currentWindowID = win_getid()

    windo if win_getid() != currentWindowID && &filetype != 'nerdtree' | close | endif
endfunction

command! Only call OnlyAndNerdtree()
```

The function gets the id of the current window with `win_getid()` then it uses `windo` do iterate through all of the windows and execute code following it.

The code test if the id of the window is different than the id of the current windo and if the filetype of its buffer is different than `nerdtree`. If both of the conditions are met, the window is closed.

And the last line creates the command `:Only` which calls the function.

**Note** `win_getid()` was only introduced in Vim 8, with previous versions of Vim a workaround must be possible wit `winnr()` but it would probably not be as easy as with `win_getid()` especially because when a window is closed, the number of the other windows are updated.

Comment: I added: `call win_gotoid(currentWindowID)` under the `windo` line to make sure that the intended window kept focus.  I also added an extra check for the tagbar plugin window after the nerdtree check which is configured to be the rightmost window which may be why I needed that.

Answer (score 0):

buffer only.

https://github.com/tracyone/t-vim/blob/master/autoload/te/tools.vim#L70-L106

```
"buffer only
nnoremap <leader>bo :call te#tools#buf_only('', '')<cr>
```